# Chrome dev tools showing weird numbers during performance profiling

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

Chrome dev tools profiler is behaving randomly weird and showing incorrect numbers during performance profiling, have someone faced similar issue recently?

I tried re-install and system restart nothing works.

Running it on Windows 11.

[image]

[image]

There are no extensions installed.
[image]